# I'm trying to use JavaScript or jQuery to load header, main, and footer html files from folder to index html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I did read a lot of the same questions and I did try all of them, but here is the problem. Be easy on please, I use PHP include on the index file to do it, but Plesk told me I will break the hosting server and I must use HTML index file.

I call the jQuery like this inside the head:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Head start -->

<head>
  
  <title>Advertron ISP - Placeholder</title>
  
  <!-- Custom stylesheets -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <!-- Advertron ISP CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/advertronisp.css"/>
  <!-- Custom font kit -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f6b2049012.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- jQuery for replacing content on main html page -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#header").load("templates/header-top.html");
      $("#main").load("main.html");
      $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<!--/ Head ends -->

<body>
  <!-- Body start here -->
  <div class="grid-container">
    <!-- Header start here -->
    <div id="header"></div>
    <!--/ Header ends -->
    <!-- Main content -->
    <div id="main"></div>
    <!--/ Main content ends -->
    <!-- Footer start here -->
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <!--/ Footer ends -->
  </div>
  <!--/ Body ends-->
</body>

</html>
```

This work and then only load the header-top.html file, but the moment I insert (templates/) where I call from the folder before (main.html) or (footer.html)

Then it doesn't load and stop by searching kit.fontawesomesome.

I'm using my localhost as testing server and I'm on Linux and Apache server is running.

Then, I also like to replaceWith() when someone clicks on a link or tab inside the main.html file an element div on the main.html must be replaced with other content.

I read that I can use XML or ajax or jQuery to do it, but all my trying to do it just doesn't work. After I can solve the first issue then maybe that will solve the second issue too.

Blessings
Christo

Comment: Note: the `<link>` and `<meta>` tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in HTML.

Comment: Hi, Rob, this is learned from strict coding years ago and old habits die hard. But that is not my problem, my problem is with calling the HTML files from the templates folder.

Comment: Actually, that's XHTML markup, which is XML, not "strict" markup, but I hear that all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp to address the problem to load header, main, and footer HTML files from folder to index HTML file.

It's much faster and it works. So if anyone else looking to do it, use the solution in W3Schools.

Blessings
Christo